# Replacing delegate with lambda expression

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

I am trying to replace following statement with the lambda expression:

```
 List<ABC> l = new List<ABC>();
  l.Find(delegate(ABC a) { return a.A == 4; });
```

I tried

```
 l.Find((ABC a)=>a.A==4;);
```

but that is obviously incorrect.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, note that it **is still a delegate** - simply: rather, it uses the *lambda syntax* rather than the *anonymous method* syntax (it essentially means exactly the same thing, though).

As for how to fix it: just take away the `;`:

```
l.Find((ABC a) => a.A == 4);
```

or more simply:

```
l.Find(a => a.A == 4);
```

(brackets are only *necessary* if you have multiple parameters; explicit types are useful for disambiguation)

Answer (score 10):

Just to be complete, any of these would be valid:

```
// Fullest version
l.Find((ABC a) => { return a.A==4; });

// Infer the type of the parameter
l.Find((a) => { return a.A==4; });

// Single parameter - can remove the ()
l.Find(a => { return a.A==4; });

// Single expression - can remove braces and semi-colon
l.Find(a => a.A == 4);
```

(You can use the "single expression" part independently of the other shortcuts.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
l.Find( (a) => a.A == 4);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know it infered the type even if it is a field of the class.great!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not use it in simple way, I think there is no need to write `(ABC a)`:

```
l.Find(a => a.A == 4);
```

This statement `l.Find((a) => a.A == 4);` can be written as your statement `l.Find(delegate(ABC a) { return a.A == 4; });`. As you seen predicate can be replaced with the anonymous method( delegate ).

(.NET 2.0)

```
 fooList.Find(delegate (Foo f) { return f.Equals(fooTarget); });
```

or (later version)

```
 fooList.Find(f => f.Equals(fooTarget));
```